# Selecting data within a pivot table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I have some VBA code which needs to select Prod. Code, Lims#, SampleID, Log Date, District Name, Region, Machine ID, Ash, cNDF, CP, Ca, Cl from a pivot table.

When I use Entire row, I can select all the data that I need to make a clean paste into column A. However, now I'd like to paste into column

```
.PivotItems(PivotFieldName.Caption).DataRange.EntireRow.Select
```

I've attempted to do just data range, however it won't pull Prod.Code, Lims#, etc columns. It will only grab the analyte columns.

```
.PivotItems(PivotFieldName.Caption).DataRange.Select
```

I also tried to do a range off of the EntireRow, however then I can't figure out how to get last column or last row for that selected Prod. Code.

```
.PivotItems(PivotFieldName.Caption).DataRange.EntireRow.Range("A1:BB1").Select
```

How can I got about getting all columns for a Prod. code selected like the Entire Row method excluding the extra rows?

The Prod.Code Columns & Rows can shift in size depending on the data so I need to make it capable of grabbing the right range.

Further code structure:

```
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld As PivotField
Set PvtTbl = Sheets("NEP Pivot").PivotTables("NEP_Pivot")
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Prod. Code")
For Each PivotFieldName In PvtFld.PivotItems
'PivotFieldName.Caption represents "EHB" 
If IsError(Application.Match(PivotFieldName.Caption, rngList, 0)) Then

With PvtFld
On Error Resume Next

.PivotItems(PivotFieldName.Caption).ShowDetail = True 'Show pivot item
.PivotItems(PivotFieldName.Caption).DataRange.EntireRow.Copy 
 Destination:=Sheets(PivotFieldName.Caption).Range("A3")
 ...
 ..
 .
```

Comment: DO you mean DataBodyRange copy? What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output within the screenshot would be A6:L10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  .DataBodyRange property instead to get all the data within the pivot

[PivotTable.DataBodyRange Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-databodyrange-property-excel)

> Returns a Range object that represents the range of values in a
>   PivotTable. Read-only.
>
> Syntax
>
> expression . DataBodyRange
>
> expression A variable that represents a PivotTable object.

As you also want the row element you can do the following you can resize the data body range according to the difference in column count between the larger TableRange2 property and that inside pivot area. Be aware that grand totals etc may affect this but this shows you how to start thinking about it. There is also a TableRange1 property available with pivots.

Example pivot:

[image]

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim columnsDifference As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable4")

    columnsDifference = pvt.TableRange2.Columns.Count - pvt.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count

    With pvt.DataBodyRange
        Debug.Print .Offset(, -columnsDifference).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count + columnsDifference).Address
    End With

End Sub
```

I would recommend reading up on referencing [pivottable ranges in VBA](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/). 
There are a variety of properties that you can use to determine ranges e.g. LabelRange and DataRange for fieldItems. You seems to have explored some of these. My experience has been that these are influenced by your pivottable layout and you will need to determine the current combination of methods to get your data.

For example, I used the following to get all the data for EHB with data laid out as follows:

[image: Data]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim columnsDifference As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("mySheetName")
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("NEP_Pivot")

    columnsDifference = pvt.TableRange2.Columns.Count - pvt.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count

    With pvt.DataBodyRange
        Debug.Print pvt.PivotFields("Prod. Code").PivotItems("EHB").LabelRange.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(pvt.PivotFields("Prod. Code").PivotItems("EHB").LabelRange.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count + columnsDifference).Address
    End With

End Sub
```

This produced the result

```
$C$11:$N$13
```

Notice how I have had to combine functions to get this result and if the pivottable layout gets changed this falls apart.

I was also able to write using:

```
With pvt.TableRange1

   Debug.Print pvt.PivotFields("Prod. Code").PivotItems("EHB").LabelRange.Resize(pvt.PivotFields("Prod. Code").PivotItems("EHB").LabelRange.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Offset(-1, 0).Address

End With
```

Comment: How are you indicating this will be done? `.PivotItems(PivotFieldName.Caption).DataBodyRange.Select` seems to do nothing. `PivotFieldName.Caption` represents "EHB". While the `With PvtFld` statment represents "Prod. Code".

Comment: It is applied to the pivot itself not the pivotitem see example above where you would use  pvt.DataBodyRange.Select for inside the pivot and something like With  pvt.DataBodyRange : .Offset(, -columnsDifference).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count + columnsDifference).Select : End With         for including the rows

Comment: If you are actually after a specific column only then different syntax is required.

Comment: Let me know how you get on

Comment: Mar, this code grabs all of the Prod. Codes, and exludes all of the Analyte Columns. As shown in my example, it needs to grab the PivotFieldName in my example "EHB" and copy all of its data. So if there are 2 product codes lets say "EHB" and "BMR" and I define "EHB" as the PivotFieldName to use, it should select only the "EHB" rows, including the analyte columns.

Comment: Without actual data it is hard for me to advise further. You can potentially union to select another column further down. Is this just one pivot?  How does analyte fit with the original source data?